# Trying to get a node over REST says 'Not acceptable format: json'

Tags: 8

(Yes there are other questions the same as this, but they're older versions and the solutions there don't work.)

I have this REST resource config `rest.resource.entity.node.yml`:

```
uuid: 248f9825-289c-4201-9f5b-a8d63cf2e5ca
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - basic_auth
    - hal
    - node
    - serialization
_core:
  default_config_hash: t_jfECmZhJqBOJuSOFn87EOi_TWi-_fRYTuJgd19vgg
id: entity.node
plugin_id: 'entity:node'
granularity: resource
configuration:
  methods:
    - GET
    - POST
    - DELETE
    - PATCH
  formats:
    - hal_json
    - json
  authentication:
    - basic_auth
```

When I go to /node/123?_format=json, I get:

```
 {"message":"Not acceptable format: json"}
```

I don't understand what's going wrong.

I can see the `rest.entity.node.GET` route in the {router} DB table. The _format property for that says 'webapp_json' rather than 'json'. Is that normal?

The full route definition from the DB is:

```
C:31:"Symfony\Component\Routing\Route":1467:{a:9:{s:4:"path";s:12:"/node/{node}";s:4:"host";s:0:"";s:8:"defaults";a:2:{s:11:"_controller";s:34:"Drupal\rest\RequestHandler::handle";s:21:"_rest_resource_config";s:6:"webapp";}s:12:"requirements";a:4:{s:7:"_access";s:4:"TRUE";s:14:"_entity_access";s:9:"node.view";s:26:"_csrf_request_header_token";s:4:"TRUE";s:7:"_format";s:11:"webapp_json";}s:7:"options";a:5:{s:14:"compiler_class";s:33:"Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteCompiler";s:10:"parameters";a:2:{s:4:"node";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:11:"entity:node";s:9:"converter";s:30:"paramconverter.latest_revision";}s:21:"_rest_resource_config";a:2:{s:4:"type";s:27:"entity:rest_resource_config";s:9:"converter";s:30:"paramconverter.latest_revision";}}s:5:"_auth";a:2:{i:0;s:10:"basic_auth";i:1;s:6:"cookie";}s:14:"_access_checks";a:3:{i:0;s:20:"access_check.default";i:1;s:19:"access_check.entity";i:2;s:24:"access_check.header.csrf";}s:4:"utf8";b:1;}s:7:"schemes";a:0:{}s:7:"methods";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"GET";}s:9:"condition";s:0:"";s:8:"compiled";C:33:"Drupal\Core\Routing\CompiledRoute":440:{a:11:{s:4:"vars";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"node";}s:11:"path_prefix";s:0:"";s:10:"path_regex";s:29:"#^/node/(?P<node>[^/]++)$#sDu";s:11:"path_tokens";a:2:{i:0;a:5:{i:0;s:8:"variable";i:1;s:1:"/";i:2;s:6:"[^/]++";i:3;s:4:"node";i:4;b:1;}i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"text";i:1;s:5:"/node";}}s:9:"path_vars";a:1:{i:0;s:4:"node";}s:10:"host_regex";N;s:11:"host_tokens";a:0:{}s:9:"host_vars";a:0:{}s:3:"fit";i:2;s:14:"patternOutline";s:7:"/node/%";s:8:"numParts";i:2;}}}}
```

Comment: OK, when the route expects a different format you get this error message. The question is which REST modules you are using. They usually adjust the router table to their needs.

Comment: I'm using core's REST with the contrib REST UI to set them up. AFAICT, that is the route from the REST module that's been defined.

Comment: I have the same problem, unless I set  also 'cookie' to the Authentication methods. Do that solve your problem? In any case it would be interesting to see if it is actually an issue and eventually if it is already reported